# Make Dynamic square div for an memory game

Tags: javascript, html, css

What is the easiest way to make responsive dynamic div-s square, like in memory game (image below).[image]

I have problem that user need to scroll down to see whole bottom part of game. How can I calculate (easiest solution) that whole my game is always visible. And also I want that to be dynamic (on image we can see 4x4 game, there should work for any number, 7x7, 10x10 and so on...).

Snippet of my code is: http://jsbin.com/nucovakevu/edit?html,css,output.
Everything in  is added dynamically by JavaScript.
It also does not work where I do zoom in.
I am beginner in front-end developing and I mixed here bootstrap and plain css, which is probably not good solution.
Also I used this css trick to make my div as responsive square:

```
 width: 23%; 
 height: 15vw;
```

It supposed to be something like:

```
 width: 23%; 
 height: 23vw;
```

but I get rectangle in this case, because I obviously do not understand very well how this work.

Comment: Writing an answer with jsfiddle :)

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. What happened when you gave it a go yourself? what did you try? What did you research on the web and why was it not satisfactory to you? Stack overflow is full of people that will help *you* to write it... but we aren't a code-writing service ;) we do expect you to do the work yourself, and it works best if you have a go, and then we help you with the bugs you come across... :)

Comment: @TarynEast agreed :)

Comment: I completely agree with you and I tried to make it more understandable. Thank you for suggestion :)

Comment: You can try doing `height:23vw; width:23vw;`?

Comment: @Kaiido It was mistake, I remove  html5-canvas  tag it should have been html5.     @ www139  height:23vw; width:23vw does not work, it makes too bug square, only 2 per row.

Answer (score 3):

Just call the function size(); whenever you want to update the grid.

Look at the comments within the code to understand better how this functions.

https://jsfiddle.net/xn5j4rcf/

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  size();
});

function size() {
  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  container.innerHTML = '';//don't want any extra boxes when you call this function again
  var x = Math.floor(window.innerWidth / 50);//width of boxes that can fit; remove any decimal places
  var y = Math.floor(window.innerHeight / 50);//height of boxes that can fit; remove any decimal places
  for (var i = 0; i < x * y; i++) {//multiply x*y to get total area of boxes that can fit
    var box = document.createElement('div');//create a div
    box.className = 'box';//assign class
    container.appendChild(box);//append
  }
}

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  size();//call the function again when the window is resized
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 4px;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 4px solid #fff;//border for margin but use border-box to make sure the width and height are still 50px
  background-color: #ddd;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#container {
  font-size: 0;//remove annoying margin from display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could edit your answer and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: I am doing that now, just takes a little time :)

Comment: @Taryn East I update my question. Thank you for suggestion and solution. Is it possible to do it without JavaScript, only with css? And this solution retains always the same size of squares, but change the number of squares depend on screen size. I thought opposite, always the same (predefined) number of squares, with dynamic dimension depending on the screen size.

Comment: I think that it would better to open a new question with the new requirements; it's a substantial change

Answer (score 0):

This approach can be achieved, but a little odd kinky skills and compatibility is not good:

DEMO: [response divs with full screen](http://codepen.io/Dudy/pen/PZGKJm?editors=110)

Here is the use of a *table-cell* flexibility and *writting-mode* to change the direction of the flow

css code blow:

```
html,body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrap{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;

  background-color: #000;
}

.row-wrap{
  display: table-cell;
}

.row{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;

  -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
}

.item{
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;

  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```